# how to use silverlight enables wcf web service in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, wcf, silverlight

We have a wcf web service which is developed as a silverlight enabled wcf web service for accessing database from silverlight application. Now we would like to use the same WCF service to be used from JavaScript. Is it possible to call silverlight enabled wcf web service in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

http://www.bendewey.com/index.php/186/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery

Modify the class definition 
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class CustomersService
{
  /////
}

Leave silverlight methods as it is and add Json methods like the following.

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public List GetCustomers(int d)
{
   return List;
}

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you just need to add the Json Endpoint to your service contract and convert your method to return Json data,

For example,

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "login/{username}/{password}",BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]

    UserAuth login(string username, string password);
```

Comment: Add "Content-Type: application/json" and "Accept: application/json" in REST Client header section

Comment: No progress. Is it possible for you paste this here

Comment: paste what? just try to consume your service using restclient

Comment: We tried this and is still giving me the error 415; paste the line of codes as you have done above. We are trying to return a string using service. Do we need to add anything in the config file (client and server are in different domains) or should we use JASONP? any help